# Why does spinner item style work, but spinner drop down item style fails?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

I've read tons of answers to related questions, but there's nothing that I've found relating to this specific issue. While the styling for the spinner item works just fine, that for the spinner drop down items is ignored. Moreover, the latter uses the former's style. It's like the spinner item's style is overriding the drop down item's style.

As an aside, I'm not interested in using the **android:popupBackground** attribute on the Spinner element. While that attribute does work to set the background color of the drop down list, I want finer control over several properties, in addition to the background color.

Here's my code:

MyFragment.java

```
mSpinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(activity, R.layout.spinner_item);
mSpinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
```

app_bar_main.xml

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/my_spinner"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/spinner_width"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spinner_margin_top"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spinner_margin_bottom"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/spinner_padding_right"/>
```

spinner_item.xml

```
<TextView
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@android:id/text1"
   style="@style/SpinnerItem"
   android:maxLines="1"
   android:ellipsize="end"
   android:textAlignment="inherit"
   android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
```

spinner_dropdown_item.xml

```
<CheckedTextView
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@android:id/text1"
   style="@style/SpinnerDropDownItem"
   android:maxLines="1"
   android:ellipsize="end"
   android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
```

styles.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">
        @style/SpinnerItem
    </item>

    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">
        @style/SpinnerDropDownItem
    </item>

    <item name="spinnerDropDownItemStyle">
        @style/SpinnerDropDownItem
    </item>
</style>

<style name="SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/spinner_item_padding_left</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/spinner_item_padding_right</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/spinner_item_text</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/spinner_item_text</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/spinner_item_background</item>
</style>

<style name="SpinnerDropDownItem">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/spinner_dropdown_item_horizontal_padding</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/spinner_dropdown_item_horizontal_padding</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/spinner_dropdown_item_text</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/spinner_dropdown_item_text</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/spinner_dropdown_item_background</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem too, only using `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner` helped me to be able to customize its style.

Comment: Didn't work when tried, which wasn't surprising because the popup information in the IDE for AppCompatSpinner states that it will automatically be used when Spinner is specified in a layout.  AppCompatSpinner is explicitly specified when writing custom views.